# Barrie England's author page 404s

Tags: bug, blog

On the [blog](http://english.blogoverflow.com/), each author has a page that lists all their posts. So if you look at an [individual post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2013/06/one-language-many-voices/) the name of the author links to [that page](http://english.blogoverflow.com/author/Barrie%20England/).

However following the above link results in a 404.

Please can this be fixed?

Comment: I bet it's the space in his name.  That happened when you posted my blog and [I took it up with meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147892/elu-blog-profile-404s).

Comment: Incidentally, mine is 404ing as well.

Comment: Oh! thanks for the pointers. I might post on metameta then.

Comment: @MattЭллен I checked the kiosks at [Matamata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matamata), but didn’t find any postings from you there.

Comment: @cornbreadninja麵包忍者 I've put a bounty on your question to see if that gets it fixed.

Comment: @MattЭллен nice!

Comment: @MattЭллен I've unaccepted the answer and updated the question.